# Python ValueError: Unable to parse string "-1,000,000.00" at position 0

Tags: python, validation

I've a data frame which is string something like this:

```
Amount
-1,000,000.00
-34,000.00
.
.
```

We'd need to convert into numeric, hence, using the following statement in Python:-

```py
val = pd.to_numeric(df, downcast='float')
```

However, getting the following error message:-

```py
ValueError: Unable to parse string "-1,000,000.00" at position 0
```

Any advice?

Comment: Replace those commas with empty strings (i.e., use something like `df.replace(',','')`).

Comment: Or `''.join(df.split(','))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`locale.atof`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html):

```
import locale
from locale import atof
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')

value = "-1,000,000.00"
print(atof(value))
# -1000000.0
```